# Undefined Offset error as a result of trying to get the sum in to an array

Tags: laravel

```
 foreach ($pos as $po) {
            $po_value[] = 0;
            $po_item_total = 0;
            foreach ($po->po_items as $po_item) {
                $po_item_total = $po_item->qty * $po_item->rate;
                $po_value[$po->id] = $po_value[$po->id] + $po_item_total;
            }
        }
```

This line

```
$po_value[$po->id] = $po_value[$po->id] + $po_item_total;
```

Causes **Undefined Offset** error.
Could you please help

Comment: You can check your variables with `dd()` function just try `dd($po)` to find out whether you are getting desired result in that variable. The error clearly says that array index is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting key to your $po_value array to be $po->id and on your first iteration of the second foreach you are looking for it and it is missing.

This should fix it:

```
$po_value[$po->id] = 0;
```

Simplified version:

```
foreach($pos as $po){
    $po_total[$po->id] = 0;
    foreach($po->po_items as $po_item){
        $po_total[$po->id]+= $po_item->qty * $po_item->rate;
    }
}
```